# Visual Studio Code complaining about basic JavaScript objects in TypeScript files

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tsconfig

I’ve just opened a project in Visual Studio Code, and it’s now complaining about not being able to find the most basic of JavaScript objects.

For example, I have this line:

```js
throw new Error('The [x-confirm] directive can only be used on form elements.');
```

And I’m getting a `Cannot find name 'Error'` error from VS Code.

Is `Error` not a built-in JavaScript class? Why is VS Code (and TypeScript) suddenly complaining about this?

This is what my **tsconfig.json** file looks like:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "DOM"
        ],
        "module": "ES6",
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "strict": true,
        "target": "ES6",
        "types": [
            "vite/client"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "resources/ts/**/*"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for [`compilerOptions.lib`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib):

> TypeScript includes a default set of type definitions for built-in JS APIs (like `Math`), as well as type definitions for things found in browser environments (like `document`). TypeScript also includes APIs for newer JS features matching the [`target`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target) you specify; for example the definition for `Map` is available if [`target`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target) is `ES6` or newer.

When you specify the `compilerOptions.lib` array, the effect is removal of those default environment types from compilation — only the ones specified in the array are included.

The `Error` global class comes from the type definitions in the `"ES5"` library (and is also included in newer ES version libraries as well, such as `"ES2015"`/`"ES6"`, `"ES2023"`, `"ESNext"`, etc.). From the [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v5.3.3/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1056-L1068):

```ts
interface Error {
    name: string;
    message: string;
    stack?: string;
}


interface ErrorConstructor {
    new (message?: string): Error;
    (message?: string): Error;
    readonly prototype: Error;
}


declare var Error: ErrorConstructor;
```

It looks like you've specified the `compilerOptions.lib` field, but haven't added any of those libraries for the core ES features to your compilation because the only value in your array is `"DOM"` (and not also — for example — `"ES6"`).

For TypeScript to recognize `Error`, you'll either need to add one of the previously mentioned `ES*` libraries to your `compilerOptions.lib` array (or remove the field entirely so that the defaults are used).

---

Below I've included some examples to demonstrate. In each example, the error diagnostic locations are indicated by wavy underlines `~~~~~~` and all correspond to the error message pattern `Cannot find name…`. You can see the TypeScript Playground links for more detailed error diagnostics:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=4&noErrorTruncation=true#code/PQgEB4CcFMDNpgOwMbVIg9gWgCZwIYCuANgC5bECWARgLwBEpkh09owAfO8KADKUBrNAGdS+SKUqIA5qADulUgAtQ0ALYAHUgE9QVaqHGR82gFygA3qHr765gNoBdUAF8AUG+QZEwjMWgAdMQY0gAUCog4GHJBGMj4kt4BSjCwAJQA3NygAHIYpKAYAqDU0PGEwmhePn5o+JHyUlFyhjCgsJAYaqAAIgDyALKgoQACOhrQwsBy0NRpoIAoBAAFckqUyCqUwogA5AUaMJWIpG7KnS2I0C0AopCdkKH0fRgawvSZ2XkFRSVlRJWgW73UBbdqdbrXADKAFZFvI1hsQds9qADpNoMc3EA)

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": []
    }
}
```

```ts
console.log(window.location.href); /* Not ok because console and window are from DOM (@types/web) — which isn't present
~~~~~~~     ~~~~~~                 */
throw new Error("Oops"); /* Not ok because Error is from ES5 — which isn't present
          ~~~~~          */
```

---

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=4&noErrorTruncation=true#code/PQgEB4CcFMDNpgOwMbVIg9gWgCZwIYCuANgC5bECWARgLwBEpkh09owAfO8KADKUBrNAGdS+SKUqIA5qADulUgAtQ0ALYAHUgE9QVaqHGR82gFygA3qHr765gNoBdUAF8AUCB5Q4CaCjT6DACiAMoAbGyc3HyCaPg4OFKy9KERoKQYejTmVjY0dqD2KeH0zu5uyBiIwhjE0AB0xBjSABQKiDgYco0YyPiSVfVKMLAAlADc0QByGKSgGAKg1NB9hMJoldW1cR3yUp1yhjCgsJAYaqAAIgDyALKgLQACOhrQwsBy0NSjoIAoBAAFciUlGQKkowkQAHI5hoYOtEKQ3MozodENBDkFIGdIC16NcMBphPQJtFrotlqt1qBMdjQOCTmcLqEAKxuIA)

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["ES6"]
    }
}
```

```ts
console.log(window.location.href); /* Not ok because console and window are from DOM (@types/web) — which isn't present
~~~~~~~     ~~~~~~                 */
throw new Error("Oops"); // Ok because Error is from ES5
```

---

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=4&noErrorTruncation=true#code/PQgEB4CcFMDNpgOwMbVIg9gWgCZwIYCuANgC5bECWARgLwBEpkh09owAfO8KADKUBrNAGdS+SKUqIA5qADulUgAtQ0ALYAHUgE9QVaqHGR82gFygA3qHr765gNoBdUAF8AUCB5Q4CaCjT6DAAiAPIAsmyc3HyCaPg4OFKy9KERoKQYejTmVjY0dqD2KeH0zu5uyBiIwhjE0AB0xBjSABQKiDgYco0YyPiSVfVKMLAAlADc0SECoNTQfYTCaJXVtXEd8lKdcoYwoLCQGGqgqaAtAAI6GtDCwHLQ1KNuyoc7iNA7AKKQh5At9CEMBphPQJtEAHIYUigDAzOYLJagb6-UCUYT7Q7HT4AZQArKBACgE8iUlGQKjRiAA5NCNDAlohSG4gA)

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["DOM"]
    }
}
```

```ts
console.log(window.location.href); // Ok because console and window are from DOM (@types/web)
throw new Error("Oops"); /* Not ok because Error is from ES5 — which isn't present
          ~~~~~          */
```

---

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=4&noErrorTruncation=true#code/PQgEB4CcFMDNpgOwMbVIg9gWgCZwIYCuANgC5bECWARgLwBEpkh09owAfO8KADKUBrNAGdS+SKUqIA5qADulUgAtQ0ALYAHUgE9QVaqHGR82gFygA3qHr765gNoBdUAF8AUCB5Q4CaCjT6DACiAMoAbGyc3HyCaPg4OFKy9KERoKQYejTmVjY0dqD2KeH0zu6eEDDwSKhZdPQAIgDyALKRXGD8QoYJSdbNbemZ+jnWtg7FEQA0-a2lrm5uyBiIwhjE0AB0xBjSABQKiDgYctsYyPiSK5tKVQCUANzRTQJuypAn6NByoEGQH5A9vQmhgNMJ6I9nq8gA)

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["ES6", "DOM"]
    }
}
```

```ts
console.log(window.location.href); // Ok
throw new Error("Oops"); // Ok
```

Comment: Thanks. I added the `"lib": ["DOM"]` as I was getting errors with `window` and `document` suddenly being undeclared, and Googling that problem suggested adding the `"lib"` key and adding `"DOM"` to that array.